# Special char comparison behavior difference between Windows and Linux

Tags: unicode, string-comparison, utf-16

I had to compare sequence of Japanese characters for sorting purpose. In Windows platform I'm using CompareStringW function and in Linux platform I'm using wcscasecmp function to compare. When comparing the below UTF-16 character sequences, the functions' output differs.

String 1 - {0x65e5, 0x672c}

String 2 - {0xff7a, 0xff8a}

In Windows, CompareStringW returns CSTR_GREATER_THAN, meaning String 1 is greater. Where as in Linux, wcscasecmp returns '-39317' meaning string 2 is greater.

The Windows function is called with flags (NORM_IGNORECASE | NORM_IGNOREKANATYPE | NORM_IGNOREWIDTH | SORT_STRINGSORT).

Can anyone kindly guide me to understand why the behavior is different between the platforms? And, is there any way to get same behavior across the platforms?

Comment: Different platforms, different APIs, different rules. Why does this surprise you that the results would be different? If you want consistent results, use the same API on both platforms. There are plenty of cross-platform Unicode APIs available.

Comment: I agree to your commets. But I trying to understand about that different rules. I tried going through Microsoft API rules. I couldn't get fair idea about it. Can you some references about cross-platform Unicode APIs? Thank you.

Comment: do you set the same locale?

Comment: Yes, US English was set on both platforms.